# How to read / change a secific value from / in a bencoded file in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a Python 3 script that uses an https API to get a randomly assigned port number from a server on a VPN.  Once I have this number, I want to change the .ini file for emule to have it use that port and start emule --easy.

Next, I want to make sure that vuze opens with a listening port != the port emule is using.  Rather than storing this in an easy to edit .ini file, Vuze uses a bencoded .config file.

If there is a relatively easy way to set this value in the config file, I would like to have the python script select a random port number, change the .config file and open vuze.

Second best would be to start vuze with the feature turned on to assign a random listening port, read the port from the .config file, and if it is the same as the emule port, close and restart vuze.

March 17:  I found py3bencode at [https://bitbucket.org/rsnitsch/py3bencode][1]  I am such a noob, though, I am not sure where to put the 4 files before running setup.py.

March 30: updated with final code:

```
def startmysoftware(portgiven):
# eMule

emuleinifile = os.environ['ProgramFiles']+'\\eMule\\config\\'+'preferences.ini'
# vvv beginning and ending quotes are to compensate for Microsoft kludge
emuleappfile = '"'+os.environ['ProgramFiles']+'\\eMule\\emule.exe'+'"'
print(emuleappfile)
# to use both Kademelia and eD2K, emule requires two different port numbers
# unfortunately, PIA's portforwarding servers only provide 1
eMuleNetworkIseD2K = True
parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read(emuleinifile)
if eMuleNetworkIseD2K:
    #set up for eD2K
    parser.set('eMule','Port',portgiven)
    parser.set('eMule','UDPPort','0')
    parser.set('eMule','NetworkKademlia','0')
    parser.set('eMule','NetworkED2K','1')
else:
    #set up for Kademelia
    parser.set('eMule','Port','1')
    parser.set('eMule','UDPPort',portgiven)
    parser.set('eMule','NetworkKademlia','1')
    parser.set('eMule','NetworkED2K','0')
with open(emuleinifile, 'w') as configfile:
    parser.write(configfile)
os.system(emuleappfile)
# Vuze
# verify vuze listening port != portgiven for emule and start vuze
vuzeconfigfile = os.environ['AppData']+'\\Azureus\\'+'azureus.config'
# vvv beginning and ending quotes are to compensate for Microsoft kludge
vuzeappfile = '"'+os.environ['ProgramFiles']+'\\Vuze\\azureus.exe'+'"'
vuzelistenport = portgiven
while vuzelistenport == portgiven:
    vuzelistenport = random.randint(49160, 65534)
# bdecode aszreus.config, set port and save
encodedconfig = open(vuzeconfigfile, 'rb').read()
mydecodedconfig=py3bencode.bdecode(encodedconfig)
mydecodedconfig['TCP.Listen.Port']=vuzelistenport
mydecodedconfig['UDP.Listen.Port']=vuzelistenport
mydecodedconfig['UDP.NonData.Listen.Port']=vuzelistenport
encodedconfig=py3bencode.bencode(mydecodedconfig)
configfile = open(vuzeconfigfile,'wb')
configfile.write(encodedconfig)
configfile.close()
os.system(vuzeappfile)
return True
```

Comment: It's much easier to programmatically parse a bencode file than an .ini file. It also makes it a little more difficult (just a little - if you know what you're doing it's easy) for people to mess it up by manually editing it, so it's a win-win. Besides, Vuze already has a bencode parser. This makes *perfect* sense.

Comment: I intend to use configparser to update the ini.  I was hoping to find a similar way to modify the bencoded config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to install **py3bencode** via `setup.py`. You can simply place `py3bencode.py` in the same directory as your main script and import it as you would import one of your own Python modules.

To retrieve py3bencode follow these instructions:

- Get [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/)
- Clone py3bencode's Mercurial repository via commandline: `hg clone https://bitbucket.org/rsnitsch/py3bencode`

You can now simply copy `py3bencode.py` in the same folder as your script.

If you insist, you can also try the `setup.py` procedure again:

- Change to the py3bencode directory: `cd py3bencode`
- Run `setup.py install` with your Python interpreter, e.g. `C:\Python33\python.exe setup.py install`

---

Once you have py3bencode at your disposal it should be straightforward to achieve what you want. Just decode Vuze's config file and let Python print the contents (hint: use Python's `pprint` module to get a readable output). Then look for the values you seek to modify.

Comment: Danke, Robert.  I installed mercurial.  I had to reboot for the Mecurial directory to be appended to the path.  I also had to manually add the pythondirectory to my path and reboot.  Once I had done this the above did the trick.  (I am not complaining, just trying to be helpful if someone would read this later...)  Now off to read about how to open this file as a bytes object to pass to bencode...

Comment: Thanks again, Robert.  I got it all working thanks to your help!  I updated the code in my original post with the final code.